# The Error .so file When 'make install' over in DREAMPlace

Tags: python, cmake, version

DREAMPlace(https://github.com/limbo018/DREAMPlace)

When I used the conda (Python 3.9) environment, I compiled the project

```
Cmake- DCMAKE_ INSTALL_ PREFIX=/home/mini liang/science/DREAMPlace/install - DPYTHON_ EXECUTABLE=[my conda Python URL]
```

But in the final generated cpython '.so' file version, it is place_ Io_ Cpp.cpython-311-x86_ 64 Linux gnu so (Python 3.11)
(python3.11 is in my Ubuntu Sysrtem)

How should I modify the compilation options or make changes to make the so file conform to the Python version in my Conda environment?

Thank you for your reply.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/minliang/science/DREAMPlace/install  -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/minliang/.conda/envs/DeepPlace/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION=3.9
```

does  not have any effect.